# Find all external URLs from my own posts

Tags: support

How can I utilize [data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/queries) to list all external URLs from own posts on SU?

Background: After reading ["I estimate 10% of the links posted here are dead. How do we deal with them?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300916/i-estimate-10-of-the-links-posted-here-are-dead-how-do-we-deal-with-them?cb=1) I tried to check at least my own posts if they have dead links

<sub>**Questions**</sub>

- Does data.stackexchange support regular expressions? Or is `like = %myString%` my only option? My quick tests said, it doesn't
- How can I build an output with 2 columns where the first one is the contained URL and the second one the associated post link. I think I have to create my own table beforehand like [it's done here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/8116/my-money-for-jam)

<sub>**Requirements**</sub>

- Find all questions and answers with my userID
- Use a [Regex expression to search for URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780194/how-to-regex-in-a-sql-query) (if possible somehow)
- If multiple URLs are found in a post, list each URL in a new row
- Sort by post date ascending (oldest to newest)

<sub>**[Where I'm currently stuck](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/edit/345535)**</sub>

```
SELECT
    p.Id as [Post Link]         
FROM    
    Posts p
WHERE 
    p.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##   and
    p.Body like '%http://%'    
ORDER BY p.CreationDate DESC
```

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq "You didn't cover my question about _______, what's wrong with you?
    Well…that's a story for another day. To get help with your Data Explorer question though, or to provide feedback, please ask on **Meta Stack Exchange!** "